# Now that Firefox no longer supports Ubuntu 18.04, what commands can uninstall Firefox? Can I save the Firefox bookmarks to use in a new browser?

Tags: 18.04, updates, firefox, support, bookmarks

I have had Firefox as the main browser for this computer for ages. I got a new computer and began spending all my time on that. It got to where there were so many Ubuntu updates for this computer after so much time not being used, attempts at installing them overwhelmed the computer and they couldn't be installed.

In the meantime, Firefox stopped supporting this version of Ubuntu. What should I do? I have no other operating system on this computer but this old version of Ubuntu. I'm using Chrome at the moment. I was thinking the easiest might be to at least uninstall Firefox and switch to Waterfox.

I also would like to discover a way I could access my bookmarks I had on Firefox and save them and use them on Waterfox.

However, maybe I should also be asking how to get the computer to accept and install the Ubuntu 18.04 updates. Is this the underlying problem? If yes, how can I fix it?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 was EOL June 2023 and therefor also off-topic here on AU.

Comment: If questions related to EOL Ubuntus are off-topic here, where does one post them? Seems like AskUbuntu should be open to *all* questions related to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Since Ubuntu 18.04 has reached end of life (which is why you stopped getting Firefox upgrades), you should upgrade to or fresh install a recent version. The latest LTS (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) would be supported until 2027.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could just install it on top of this unsupported version and have it clean up what it can't use from the old version and incorporate what it can use such as the Home file. But I guess that is asking too much. Right? I'd love to be wrong about this.

Comment: You can directly upgrade from the update manager. It does what you want